# How to mock the SimpleXMLElement in PHP using phpunit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, simplexml

I have the following function:

```
function get_svg_dimensions($svg)
    {
        $svg = simplexml_load_file($svg);
        $width = 0;
        $height = 0;

        if ($svg) {
            $attributes = $svg->attributes();

            if (isset($attributes->width, $attributes->height)) {
                $width = intval($attributes->width);
                $height = intval($attributes->height);
            } elseif (isset($attributes->viewBox)) {
                $sizes = explode(' ', $attributes->viewBox);

                if (isset($sizes[2], $sizes[3])) {
                    $width = intval($sizes[2]);
                    $height = intval($sizes[3]);
                }
            }
        }

        return ['width' => $width, 'height' => $height];
    }
```

I am trying to mock the `$attributes = $svg->attributes();`.

This is the test:

```
public function testGetSvgDimension()
    {
        $mockAttributes = [
            'width' => '100px',
            'height' => '100px',
            'viewBox' => '0 0 100 100',
        ];

        $mockSimpleXmlElement = (object)[
            '@attributes' => $mockAttributes
        ];

        $expected_value = [
            'width' => '100px',
            'height' => '100px',
        ];

        Functions\when('simplexml_load_file')->justReturn($mockSimpleXmlElement);
        $request = $this->createMock(SimpleXMLElement::class);
        $request->expects($this->once())->method('attributes')->willReturn($mockAttributes);

        static::assertEquals($expected_value, sg_core_t_get_svg_dimensions('mock_path'));
    }
```

I am getting the following error on this line
`$request = $this->createMock(SimpleXMLElement::class);`:

```
Mock_SimpleXMLElement_eba23fd5::__phpunit_setReturnValueGeneration(): Node no longer exists
```

I have tried using `Traversable::class` instead of `SimpleXMLElement::class` in `$request = $this->createMock(Traversable::class);`, but in this case I am getting the following warning:

```
Trying to configure method "attributes" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

which is turning the test coverage percentage on this function to 0.

`PHPUnit` version is `7.5.20`. I can't upgrade to 8 or 9, because the website is built using WordPress, an WordPress is currently only compatible with `PHPUnit` up to `7.x`.
`PHP` version is `7.2.26`.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Don't mock it, provide some predefined fixture for `$svg` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

basically, what I was doing wrong, was that I was returning a wrong value here:
`Functions\when('simplexml_load_file')->justReturn($mockSimpleXmlElement);`
and then trying to mock the `SimpleXMLElement` class.

What I should've done is that I should've returned a `SimpleXMLElement` when mocking `simplexml_load_file` and add attributes to it.

See the full code:

```
public function dataProvider_GetSvgDimensions()
    {
        return [
            'height and width attributes exist on the svg' => [
                (object)[
                    'width' => '100',
                    'height' => '100',
                ]
            ],
            'height and width attributes do not exist on the svg - viewBox exists' => [
                (object)[
                    'viewBox' => '0 0 100 100',
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider dataProvider_GetSvgDimensions
     *
     * @param $mockAttributes
     */
    public function testGetSvgDimension($mockAttributes)
    {
        $expected_value = [
            'width' => '100',
            'height' => '100',
        ];

        $mockSimpleXmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement('<root />');
        foreach ($mockAttributes as $attr => $value) {
            $mockSimpleXmlElement->addAttribute($attr, $value);
        }

        Functions\when('simplexml_load_file')->justReturn($mockSimpleXmlElement);

        static::assertEquals($expected_value, sg_core_t_get_svg_dimensions('mock_path'));
    }
```